# How to plot multiple sub-plots based on one column with-respect-to another column?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, seaborn, data-visualization

I am working on 'Employee-Job-Satisfaction' level based on different 'Job-roles'. I've analyzed the Data and also plot a Graph . But it doesn't work well even if would do some styling or formatting( Once have a look below ). Instead I decided to plots individual 'Employee-Job-Satisfaction' plots for each 'Job-role'.

Code I've used :

```
sns.countplot(x='EmpJobSatisfaction', hue='EmpJobRole' , data=comp2)
```

Output:
[image: On x-axis there are employee job satisfaction levels : (1,2,3,4)]

It would be convineint to plots individual graphs , So that I can easily interpret the Satisfaction level of each job type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `catplot` and specify the role as the column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

roles = ['role' + str(i) for i in range(12)]

comp2 = pd.DataFrame({'EmpJobSatisfaction':np.random.randint(1,4,500),
                    'EmpJobRole':np.random.choice(roles,500)
                     })
sns.catplot(data=comp2,x='EmpJobSatisfaction',col="EmpJobRole",kind="count",col_wrap=3,height=1.2,aspect=2)
```

[image]

Or do a stacked barplot:

```
pd.crosstab(comp2['EmpJobRole'],comp2['EmpJobSatisfaction']).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]